# Python gdalwarp incorrectly resample raster files

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I am using gdalwarp of GDAL3.1.4 to resample a raster from (0.0125, 0.00833 degree) to (0.03125, 0.025 degree). To do so, I used the following code:

```
ds= gdal.Open("test.tif", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
xmin=118
xmax=150
ymin=20
ymax=48
ds.Res =gdal.Warp("Resample_test.tif", ds, xRes= 0.03125, yRes= 0.025, 
     resampleAlg= "average", outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32, outputBounds= 
     (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
```

I believe that the "average" resampling method would consider all contributing pixels (in this case 2.5 pixels in the longitude and 3 pixels in the altitude) and return the weighted average. However, gdal.Warp returned "incorrect" values (as explained in the following figure)

[image]

Does anyone have an explanation?

PS. Same problem occurred with GDAL3.3.1